# Create a automatic list of staff assigned to a trainer

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet where "A" contains the names of trainers (This list repeats one of three names). Column "B" contains the names of employees that are assigned to those trainers (This list is unique). Other columns in this sheet are used to track observations that are conducted by the trainers.

I want to create a separate sheet that lists the names of the employees under the names of the trainers (i.e. column "A" would list all the names assigned to Lisa, column "B" those of Angela, etc). That list would also update automatically when an employee is added or removed from the other sheet.

Not sure how to do that.

Example of what I want:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4XJF.png)

Comment: Any sample data to share/outcome screenshot you have in mind?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Since you have not provided sample data so that I've assumed the "Employee-Trainers Database" on the basis of OP:**

[image]

*Write this Array Formula in Cell `A3` of `Sheet 2`, finish with `Ctrl+Shift+enter` & fill right:*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$4:$A$9,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$4:$B$9=A$2,ROW(Sheet1!$A$4:$A$9)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!$A$4:$A$9))+1),ROWS($A$3:A3))),"")}
```

**Note,** *adjust cell references in formula as needed.*

Comment: Like that, but instead of listing the trainer name under the employee, there would be a list of employees under each trainer name. Like, "Mark" would have a list under him with "Angela", "Jason", and any other names associated with him.

Comment: Added an example of what I'm looking for in OP.

Comment: This was it. I just had to change the references to reference the opposite of what you put. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help you @BenHolman, keep asking, have nice time ☺